# HERE-API Batch Geocoding Stuck on Submitted (Body Formatting Issue?)

Tags: here-api

I am working with Here-API batch geocoding.

Currently, I'm having an issue where I'm able to submit the request and receive a submitted response but the request never leaves submitted. I saw another post a few months back that said HERE had some downtime or something, but I suspect in my case the issue may be body formatting where the body I submit isn't being correctly read.

I followed the API guide but it wasn't 100% clear on which format to use. Currently I have it set to raw > json with this text:

```
    recId|searchText|country
    0001|City, State|USA
```

Is there some code formatting I'm missing with this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the status of this job?

Check the life cycle of a Batch Job here:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-lifecycle.html

and https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/job-status.html

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/example-get-status.html

Comment: Job status remains as submitted even from over the weekend.